# Create and assign value back from View bag to Text box in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have to create a textbox from a viewbag property in MVC. I could do the mapping like      `@Html.TextBox("Comments", (string)ViewBag.Comments)` but how do I read it back when the page is posted to the server. It is not filling the viewbag property back. I am very new to MVC so maybe don't understand the concept totally .

Thanks

Comment: `ViewBag` is for passing values from the controller to the view (not the other way around). When you post, your form collection will contain a value for the key `Comments` (the name of your control) but you would be better of creating a view model representing the properties you want to edit and let MVC do all the binding for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewBag wont get updated from your view and that is not the way to get data from your form. Rather, you should either use strongly typed model binding to read your data from your Action Method or you can simply check for the key in your Forms data. I am showing you example for both:

Example 1: Strongly typed model binding.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(string comments)
    {
        // the Comment from the text box.

        return View();
    }
```

Example 2: Reading from Posted Data:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction()
    {
        // the Comment from the text box.
        string comments = Request.Form["comments"];

        return View();
    }
```

I hope, you will like to use the Example 1.

Anyway, the best practice would be to bind your View with a Model class and use HtmlHelper for generating the text box like :

Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments)

Where your Model class contains a property named Comments.

And your action method should accept the same Model type as argument. Here is an example:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
    {
        string comments = model.Comments;

    }
```

And you should bind your View with the model of type MyModel.

I can understand that, as you are new to MVC, this may not make clear sense now, so, I would suggest you to check out some basic MVC tutorial. You can start from here : http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials